# ESLint issue when using babel module-resolver and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, babeljs, eslint

TS is not inferring the type when using resolved imports, but it does when using relative imports.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Discover.tsx]

useTheme has

> "Unsafe call of an 'any' typed value."

This error does not show up if i use a relative import instead of `'@theme/Theme'`

[image: useTheme]

My project structure is:

[image: project structure]

Here are my config files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json", // standard tsconfig params
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    "baseUrl": "." /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/common/components/*"],
      "@theme/*": ["./src/lib/theme/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./src/common/hooks/*"],
      "@features/*": ["./src/features/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./typings",
      "../../node_modules/@types"
    ] /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
  },
  "include": ["../"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    [
      'module:react-native-dotenv',
      {
        moduleName: '@env',
        path: '.env',
      },
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          '@components': './src/common/components',
          '@theme': ['./src/lib/theme'],
          '@hooks': ['./src/common/hooks'],
          '@features': ['./src/features'],
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
        root: '.',
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "root": true,
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-typescript", // React "airbnb-typescript/base" for just js. "airbnb","airbnb/base" for no TypeScript
    "airbnb/hooks", // React
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "@react-native-community" // React Native only
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", // TypeScript only
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json", // TypeScript only
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true }
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "babel-module": {}
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["import", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["*.config.js"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      /** Testing Files Extensions */
      "files": ["*.{spec,test}.{js,ts,tsx}", "e2e/*.{js,ts,tsx}"],
      "plugins": ["jest"],
      "env": { "jest/globals": true },
      "rules": {
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0 // Allow dev-dependency imports
      }
    }
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "args": "none",
        "caughtErrors": "none",
        "ignoreRestSiblings": true,
        "vars": "all"
      }
    ],
    // resolve "import/extensions"
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
    ],
    "curly": ["error", "multi-line"],
    "no-void": ["error"], // Allow void as statement in order to ignore promise returns
    "prettier/prettier": 0, // Disable Prettier
    "import/no-cycle": 0, // Slows down all linting
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0, // Enable Prop Spreading
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": 0, // Allow boilerplate empty interfaces for defining component props explicitly
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
      2,
      {
        "leadingUnderscore": "allow",
        "format": ["camelCase", "PascalCase", "UPPER_CASE", "snake_case"],
        "selector": "variable"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": 0, // disabled to avoid using any type
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": [2, { "ignoreIIFE": true }], // Fixes issue where async await syntax wasn't being recognised.
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      0,
      { "allowExpressions": false }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [2, { "varsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],

    // Fixes false-positives for enums in typescript https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2484#issuecomment-687257773
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": ["error"],
    "max-len": [
      "warn",
      {
        "code": 120,
        "tabWidth": 2,
        "ignoreComments": true,
        "ignoreStrings": true,
        "ignoreRegExpLiterals": true,
        "ignoreTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to install and setup [eslint-import-resolver-babel-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-babel-module), according to this blog post: https://www.robinwieruch.de/babel-module-resolver/ I don't see eslint config for it in your question.

Comment: @UgurEren I have done that but still getting the same isuse

Answer (score 0):

if you work in vscode, try use "TypeScript: Select TypeScript version" to select you workspace version